# JavaScript String split how?

Tags: javascript, imacros

Help!
how can I extract that id.
How to extract only this "gpf_3015736389"
Thank!

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split(' ')[9];") 
not functioning properly
why?

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=ID:gpf_3015736389.submit EXTRACT=htm

<input style="outline: 1px solid blue;" data-moderate="send rs mode" data-save="save" id="gpf_3015736389.submit" class="button-pro __disabled" value="share" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract ATTR=ID: value using regex

```
var line = "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=ID:gpf_3015736389.submit EXTRACT=htm";
var id = line.match(/ATTR=ID:\s*([^\n\r\ \.]*)/)[1];
console.log(id); // "gpf_3015736389"
```